# Powershell XML importnode from different file

Tags: xml, powershell

Content of profile.xml:

```
<files>
  <file folder="CaptureServer" filename="CSConfig" object="CSConfig">
    <Profile name="BBH1200Kofax">
      <OutputCache>\</OutputCache>
      <EncryptedConnectionString>564rgr=</EncryptedConnectionString>
      <ConvertDocsBeforeRelease>false</ConvertDocsBeforeRelease>
    </Profile>
  </file>
  <file folder="CaptureServices3" filename="CSConfig" object="CSConfig">
    <Profile name="BBH1200Kofax">
      <ReleaseToEnterprise>true</ReleaseToEnterprise>
      <CaptureServerUrl />
      <OutputCache />
      <Credentials>
        <EncryptedPassword>46s4rg=</EncryptedPassword>
        <UserName />
        <Domain />
      </Credentials>
      <ConvertDocsBeforeRelease>false</ConvertDocsBeforeRelease>
    </Profile>
  </file>
</files>
```

Content of rules.xml:

```
<file folder="" filename="Rules" object="ArrayOfIBarcodeRule">
  <Profile name="Test471">
    <IBarcodeRule>
      <RuleName>DOC-TESTTESTTEST-Code128</RuleName>
      <FieldSequenceNumber>1</FieldSequenceNumber>
      <FieldRectangle>
        <Location>
          <X>0</X>
          <Y>0</Y>
        </Location>
        <Size>
          <Width>0</Width>
          <Height>0</Height>
        </Size>
      </FieldRectangle>
      <SeparationValue>TESTTESTTEST</SeparationValue>
    </IBarcodeRule>
  </Profile>
</file>
```

I am trying to add the entire contents of rules.xml (the file node) as another node in profile.xml. As you can see, there are a bunch of other file nodes in the profile.xml, and the rules.xml would be another one.

This is the code I have tried, and it does not seem to do anything:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content ".\profile.xml")
$newxml = [xml](Get-Content ".\rules.xml")
$xml.ImportNode($newxml.get_DocumentElement(), $true)
$xml.Save(".\profile.xml")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're really close but ImportNode only makes a copy and doesn't actually insert the copied nodes into the document.  Try this:

```
$newNode = $newxml.ImportNode($xml.get_DocumentElement(), $true)
$newxml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newNode)
$xml.Save("$pwd\profile.xml")
```

Answer (score -2):

Content of 1.xml

```
<files><file>123</file><file>456</file><br></files>
```

Content of 2.xml

```
<file>789</file>
```

Powershell:

```
$oXML = [xml](Get-Content "1.xml")
$oNewXml = [xml](Get-Content "2.xml")
$oNewNode = $oXML.ImportNode($oNewXml.get_DocumentElement(), $true)
$oXML.DocumentElement.AppendChild($oNewNode)
$oXML.Save("3.xml")
```

This Works fine for me