# How to import CHILDREN nodes from one XML file to another

Tags: xml, powershell

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944885/powershell-xml-importnode-from-different-file) is about importing a whole XML file into another. I do not want to import WHOLE, I want to import CHILDREN. I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```psh
$xml_catalog=[xml]@'
<catalogue date_maj="2015-10-10T19:04:51">
                <products>
                               <product id="1">Pdt1</product>
                               <product id="2">Pdt2</product>
                </products>
                <categories>
                               <category id="1">cat1</category>
                               <category id="2">cat2</category>
                </categories>  
</catalogue>
'@

$xml_catalog_target = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<catalogue date_maj="2015-10-12T19:04:51">
</catalogue>
'@

Foreach ($Node in $xml_catalog.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
    $xml_catalog_target.DocumentElement.AppendChild($xml_catalog.ImportNode($Node, $true))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read closely. You need to import the nodes into the **target** XML structure:

```psh
Foreach ($Node in $xml_catalog.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
    $xml_catalog_target.DocumentElement.AppendChild($xml_catalog_target.ImportNode($Node, $true))
}
```