# Trying to import XML children from one file to another

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134611/how-to-import-children-nodes-from-one-xml-file-to-another) post and found that it is almost exactly what I need to do. However, I am not able to produce the output expected given the suggestion in this post. Basically, I am trying to import `</parameter>` elements from an XML (`$ManifestFile`) file that contains something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plasterManifest
  schemaVersion="1.1"
  templateType="Project" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/PowerShell/Plaster/v1">
  <metadata>
    <name>PlasterTestProject</name>
    <id>4c08dedb-7da7-4193-a2c0-eb665fe2b5e1</id>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <title>Testing creating custom Plaster Template for CI/CD</title>
    <description>Testing out creating a module project with Plaster for complete CI/CD files.</description>
    <author>Catherine Meyer</author>
    <tags></tags>
  </metadata>
  <parameters>
        <parameter name='AuthorName' type="user-fullname" prompt="Module author's name" />
        <parameter name='ModuleName' type="text" prompt="Name of your module" />
        <parameter name='ModuleDescription' type="text" prompt="Brief description on this module" />
        <parameter name='ModuleVersion' type="text" prompt="Initial module version" default='0.0.1' />
        <parameter name='GitLabUserName' type="text" prompt="Enter the GitLab Username to be used" default="${PLASTER_PARAM_FullName}"/>
        <parameter name="GitLubRepo" type="text" prompt="GitiLab repo name for this module" default="${PLASTER_PARAM_ModuleName}"/>
        <parameter name='ModuleFolders' type = 'multichoice' prompt='Please select folders to include' default='0,1'>
            <choice label='&amp;Public' value='Public' help='Folder containing public functions that can be used by the user.'/>
            <choice label='&amp;Private' value='Private' help='Folder containing internal functions that are not exposed to users'/>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</plasterManifest>
```

The document (`$NewManifestFile`) I'm trying to import into looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plasterManifest schemaVersion="1.1" templateType="Project" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/PowerShell/Plaster/v1">
  <metadata>
     <name>test3</name>
     <id>8c028f40-cdc6-40dc-8442-f5256a8c0ed9</id>
     <version>0.0.1</version>
     <title>test3</title>
     <description>SDSKL</description>
     <author>NAME</author>
    <tags> </tags>
  </metadata>
  <parameters>
  </parameters>
  <content>
  </content>
</plasterManifest>
```

The code I have written looks something like:

```bsh
$ManifestFile = [xml](Get-Content ".\PlasterManifest.xml")
$NewManifestFile = [xml](Get-Content $PlasterMetadata.Path)
$NewManifestFile.plasterManifest.metadata.name

$Parameters = $ManifestFile.SelectSingleNode("//plasterManifest/parameters/parameter")
$Parameters
$NewParameters = $NewManifestFile.SelectSingleNode("//plasterManifest/parameters")
#Importing the parameters and content
foreach ($parameter in $Parameters) {
   $NewParamElem = $ManifestFile.ImportNode($parameter, $true)
   $NewParameters.AppendChild($NewParamElem)
}
[void]$NewManifestFile.save($PlasterMetadata.Path)
```

Now, it doesn't error out, but it also doesn't import at all. It seems as though some element is not being assigned properly somewhere. I have tried so many alternatives, and this seems to be the only one that is close to what I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373489/1630171) pointed out, your XML documents have namespaces, so you need a namespace manager when selecting nodes with XPath expressions. Using dot-access for selecting the nodes gets you around namespace management, but since dot-access doesn't always work the way one might expect I'd still recommend sticking with `SelectNodes()` and using proper namespace managers.

```powershell
$uri = 'http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/PowerShell/Plaster/v1'

[xml]$ManifestFile = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\old.xml'
$nm1 = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $ManifestFile.NameTable
$nm1.AddNamespace('ns1', $uri)

[xml]$NewManifestFile = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\new.xml'
$nm2 = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $NewManifestFile.NameTable
$nm2.AddNamespace('ns2', $uri)

$ManifestFile.SelectNodes('//ns1:parameter', $nm1) | ForEach-Object {
    $newnode = $NewManifestFile.ImportNode($_, $true)
    $parent  = $NewManifestFile.SelectSingleNode('//ns2:parameters', $nm2)
    $parent.AppendChild($newnode) | Out-Null
}

$NewManifestFile.Save('C:\path\to\new.xml')
```

Comment: Yes, I did read that dot-access can pose some unwanted effects. I have dealt a little with XML manipulation, and chose XPath expressions last time, but I thought it would've been easier to use dot-access. Lesson learned. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your current approach:

- You're not *importing* the elements from the source document into the destination document, even though that is a prerequisite for inserting it into the destination document's DOM.
- You're using `.SelectSingleNode()` to select the source-document nodes, even though - I presume - you meant to use `.SelectNodes()` to select *all* `<parameter>` elements.
- **You're missing *namespace management*** for the documents, which is a **prerequisite for successful XPath queries via `.SelectSingleNode()` / `.SelectNodes()`**.

  - Given that namespace management is complex, the **solution below relies on [PowerShell's XML DOM dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375)**, which your question *partly* employs, which **avoids the need for namespace handling**, along with a *workaround*. If you do want to deal with namespaces - which is the strictly correct way to do it - see [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379117/45375).

---

Here's an annotated solution:

```powershell
$ManifestFile = [xml](Get-Content -Raw ./PlasterManifest.xml)
$NewManifestFile = [xml](Get-Content -Raw $PlasterMetadata.Path)

# Get the <parameters> element in the *source* doc.
# Note that PowerShell's dot notation-based access to the DOM does
# NOT require namespace management.
$ParametersRoot = $ManifestFile.plasterManifest.parameters

# Get the parent of the <parameter> elements, <parameters>, in the *destination* doc.
# Note: Ideally we'd also use dot notation in order for this, 
#       but since the target <parameters> element is *empty*, 
#       PowerShell represents it as a *string* rather than as an XML element.
#       Instead, we use the type-native index indexer ([...]) to get the
#       (first and only) <parameters> child element of the 
#       <plasterManifest> element by name.
$NewParametersRoot = $NewManifestFile.plasterManifest['parameters']

# Import the source element's subtree into the destination document, so it can
# be inserted into the DOM later.
$ImportedParametersRoot = $NewManifestFile.ImportNode($ParametersRoot, $True)

# For simplicity, replace the entire <parameters> element, which
# obviates the need for a loop.
# Note the need to call .ReplaceChild() on the .documentElement property,
# not on the document object itself.
$null = $NewManifestFile.documentelement.ReplaceChild($ImportedParametersRoot, $NewParametersRoot)

# Save the modified destination document.
$NewManifestFile.Save($PlasterMetadata.Path)
```

---

**Optional background information:**

- The **`.SelectSingleNode()` / `.SelectNodes()`** methods, because they accept [XPath queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), are the **most flexible and powerful methods for locating elements** (nodes) of interest in an XML document, but they do **require *explicit namespace handling*** if the input document declares namespaces (such as `xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/PowerShell/Plaster/v1"` in your case):

  - Note: If a given input document declares namespace and you neglect to handle them as described below, `.SelectSingleNode()` / `.SelectNodes()` simply return `$null` for all queries, if unqualified element names are used (e.g., `parameters`) and *fails* with namespace-qualified (namespace-prefixed) ones (e.g., `plaster:parameters`).
  - Namespace handling involves these steps (note that a given document may have *multiple* namespace declarations, but for simplicity the instructions assume only one):

    - Instantiate a namespace manager and associate it with the input document['s name table].
    - Associate the namespace's URI with a symbolic identifier. If the namespace declaration in the input document is for the *default* namespace - `xmlns` - you cannot use that as your symbolic identifier (the name `xmlns` is reserved) and must simply *choose* one.
    - Then, when you call `.SelectSingleNode()` / `.SelectNodes()`, you *must* use this symbolic identifier as an element-name prefix in your query strings; e.g., if your (self-chosen) symbolic identifer is `plaster` and you're looking for element `parameters` anywhere in the document, you'd use query string `'//plaster:pararameters'`
    - [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379117/45375) demonstrates all that.
  - Consider **PowerShell's `Select-Xml` cmdlet** as an alternative: as a high-level wrapper around `.SelectNodes()` it too supports XPath queries, but makes namespace management easier - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181458/45375).
- By contrast, **PowerShell's dot notation is always *namespace-agnostic***, so it requires *no* explicit namespace handling.

  - **Caveat**: While this reduces complexity, you should only use it if you know that proper namespace handling is not a necessity for processing the input document correctly.
  - **PowerShell's dot notation:**

    - PowerShell conveniently maps the XML document's DOM - the hierarchy of nodes in the input document - onto a nested object with properties, allowing you to *drill down* into the document with regular dot notation; e.g., the equivalent of XPath query `'/root/elem'` would be `$xmlDoc.root.elem`
      However, this implies that you can only use this notation to access elements whose path in the hierarchy you already know - queries are not supported (though an XPath-enabled [`Select-Xml` *cmdlet*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?) exits).
    - This mapping *ignores* namespace qualifiers (prefixes), so you must use the *mere element name*, without any namespace prefix; e.g., if the input document has a `plaster:parameters` element, you must refer to it as just `parameters`.
    - As **convenient** as dot notation is, it comes with **pitfalls**, the most notable of which is that **quasi-leaf elements** - those that either have no child nodes at all or only *non-element* child nodes such as a text node - are **returned as *strings***, not *elements*, which makes it difficult to modify them.
      Also, there is the potential for **name collisions** between the type-native properties and the properties added by PowerShell reflecting the specific document's element and attribute names - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).
      In short: **the mapping between the XML DOM and PowerShell's object model isn't - and cannot be - exact and complete**.