# Powershell not displaying rss feed

Tags: powershell, rss

I am trying to parse an RSS feed using powershell, however when i use Invoke-RestMethod this is the only output that i get:

```
xml                           RDF
---                            ---
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" RDF
```

I have had this issue with multiple rss feeds where nothing gets displayed, how can i get it working so that the RSS feed is actually displayed when I use Invoke-RestMethod?

```
$url = 'http://www.aero-news.net/news/rssfeed.xml'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're getting implies that **`Invoke-RestMethod`** worked as intended: it **returned a `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance that is an XML *DOM* (document object model) of the XML *text* returned** from the site.

Unfortunately, **the *default display formatting* for `[xml]` instances, as shown in your question, isn't very helpful<sup>[1]</sup>, but all the information is there**, which you can simply verify by accessing the **`.OuterXml` property**:

```bash
# Get the XML DOM object parsed from the website's XML text output.
$xml = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://www.aero-news.net/news/rssfeed.xml'
# Output its text representation.
$xml.OuterXml
```

The above prints a string such as:

```bash
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
        
<channel rdf:about="http://www.aero-news.net">
<title>Aero-News Network</title>
<description>Daily, Real-Time news and information critical to aviation and aerospace personnel the world over. Aero-News provides daily newsletter summaries, RSS feeds, and numerous personal and professional syndication and news distribution options to insure that aviators, the world over, are kept up to date on information of critical concern.</description>
<link>http://www.aero-news.net</link>

...
```

You can therefore **work with the `[xml]` (`XmlDocument`) instance as usual**:

- Using **PowerShell's convenient adaptation of the XML DOM via *property-based dot-notation***; e.g., `$xml.RDF.channel.about` returns string `http://www.aero-news.net`, which is the text content of the `about` *attribute* of the *element* whose path (from the document root) is `/RDF/channel`, *irrespective of namespaces*<sup>[2]</sup>; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) for more information.
- Using the **`[xml]` type's native properties and methods, such as the  XPath-based [`.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes) method** for extracting information from the XML document; however, this is **less convenient if *XML namespaces* are involved** (such as in your case), because they require explicit management; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373489/45375) for more information.

---

If you want to **pretty-print the XML text**:

The `[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`) type doesn't have built-in support for pretty-printing its text content.

While it's possible to use a [`System.Xml.XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlWriter) instance, doing so is verbose and cumbersome; however, it does offer you control over the *specifics* of the pretty-printing format.

A pragmatic, much simpler solution is to use the [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument) type instead (for which PowerShell does *not* provide dot notation, unfortunately), whose `.ToString()` method pretty-prints *by default*, using indentation with two space characters, as the following example demonstrates:

```bash
# Create a sample XmlDocument instance, as would be returned
# from an Invoke-RestMethod call (from a site returning XML text):
$xml = [xml] ('<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk101"><title>De Profundis</title></book></catalog>')

# Cast to [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] via .OuterXml; the former's
# .ToString() method then pretty-prints automatically.
([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xml.OuterXml).ToString()
```

The above yields the following string:

```xml
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <title>De Profundis</title>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

Note that the XML declaration is *not* included, but you can easily prepend it yourself:

```bash
$xd = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xml.OuterXml
$xd.Declaration.ToString() + "`n" + $xd.ToString()
```

The following **`Format-Xml` convenience function** wraps this functionality:

```bash
function Format-Xml {

  param(
   [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
   [xml] $Xml
  )

  process {
    $xd = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $Xml.OuterXml
    if ($xd.Declaration) {
      $str = $xd.ToString()
      $newline = ("`n", "`r`n")[$str.Contains("`r`n")]
      $xd.Declaration.ToString() + $newline + $str
    }
    else {
      $xd.ToString()
    }
  }

}
```

Now you can use the following to pretty-print the original `$xml` variable (obtained via `Invoke-RestMethod`):

```bash
# Outputs a pretty-printed version of the document's XML text.
$xml | Format-Xml
```

---

<sup>[1] What is being shown is the content of the document's XML declaration as property `.xml`, and the name of the document (root) element as a property named for itself. Printing any given element in the document works as follows: if the element has neither attributes nor child elements, its text content (text child node), if any, is printed. Otherwise, its attributes and their values are printed, followed by properties named for the child elements, each represented by their name as the property *value* too, if they have attributes and/or child elements themselves, otherwise by their text content, if any.</sup>

<sup>[2] An example command that processes all feed items whose title contains a given word and transforms them into custom objects.</sup>

```bash
$userTerm = 'Quote'
$xml.RDF.Item | ? Title -like "*$userTerm*" | % { 
  [PSCustomObject]@{ 
    Source = "aero"
    Title = $_.Title 
    Link = $_.Link
    Description = $_.description 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-WebRequest parses the RSS feed data as xml. You can just access the data like an ordinary object. A demo:

```
$feed = [xml]( invoke-webrequest "https://arminreiter.com/feed/" )
$feed.rss.channel.item | Select-Object @{Name="Id";Expression={$_."post-id".InnerText}}, title, link, pubDate
```

Comment: thanks, however this does not work with the rss feeds that I am trying to use, I still get no output

Comment: This is just a technique that you have to use for your own RSS feed reading the xml.

Comment: It is `Invoke-RestMethod`, not `Invoke-WebRequest` that returns _parsed XML_ (an `XmlDocument` instance directly, given an XML source);  `Invoke-WebRequest` returns a response object whose `.Content` property contains the XML _as text_, which you then have to _parse yourself_, which is what your `[xml]` cast does; this only works because the response object _as a whole_ stringifies to the value of its `.Content` property. Overall, @Dave's own approach with `Invoke-RestMethod` is simpler and more efficient - and works just fine, but that's not obvious from the default display formatting.

Comment: Yes you're right. Invoke-WebRequest doesn't always parse content as XML. I have found most times it gets source code as html.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` _never_ parses content as XML; it returns the text content returned by the site - whatever its format - in `.Content`, and - in Windows PowerShell _only_ - it parses _HTML_, via the `.ParsedHtml` property (no longer available in PowerShell [Core] 6+). Your answer, as currently written, is a distraction, and likely also a source of confusion for future readers.