# powershell replace newline not working: `n

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, text-files, newline

I have a gpx file, which is just xml, and want to run a powershell script to delete the < time > node.

```xml
    <trkpt lat="-33.483478" lon="150.159805">
    <name> p2 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:00:12Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="-33.483852" lon="150.158309">
    <name> p3 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:00:56Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="-33.483943" lon="150.157897">
    <name> p4 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:01:07Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="-33.484066" lon="150.157592">
    <name> p5 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:01:17Z</time>
    </trkpt>
```

each line ends in just LF or \n. I want to delete the < time > node including the newline.

I know I have the correct newline, or EOL, because I can see this clearly in Notepad++ and the regex in this works perfectly `<time>(.*?)</time>\n` .

so I use powershell with this code:

```
(gc test.gpx) -replace '<time>(.*?)</time>`n', '' | Out-File -encoding ASCII processed1.gpx
```

all my research shows newline for powershell is  `` `n `` (not `\n`). I have also tried `` `r`n `` and double quotes `` "`n" `` or `` "`r`n" `` just in case, and its just not working. I have searched similar questions and their answers dont seem to work for me.

Help appreciated!!

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: For robustness, it is **always preferable to use a dedicated XML parser to manipulate XML**, such as the .NET [`[xml] (System.Xml.XmlDocument)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) type - see the bottom section.

As for **what you tried**:

- **[`Get-Content` (`gc`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) reads files *line by line* by default**, and since the resulting lines have any trailing newline removed from them, the [`-replace`,operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) by definition cannot find any newlines to match - and, because an *array* of strings (lines) is provided as the input, `-replace` operates *on each line*.

  - Add the **`-Raw`** switch to **read the entire file *in full***, as a *single, multi-line string* instead.
- While it is true that you need escape sequence **`` `n ``** to represent a newline (LF) character in PowerShell, that **only works in [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)**.

  - While you *could* change the quoting of the regex to `"..."`, the better approach is to use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) and **use the *regex* escape sequence, `\n`**, to represent a newline (which PowerShell simply *passes through* to the .NET regex engine that underlies its regex features, such as the `-replace` operator).
  - Additionally, you may want to use **`\r?\n`** in order to handle both Windows-format CRLF and Unix-format LF-only newlines.

Therefore (note that omitting the replacement string is the same as passing `''`):

```sh
(gc -Raw test.gpx) -replace '<time>(.*?)</time>\r?\n'
```

---

**XML-parsing solution:**

```sh
# Sample input, wrapped in a <xml> element.
# To load from a file, use. Load() with a *full file path*:
#   ($xml = [xml]::new()).Load("$PWD/test.gpx")
($xml = [xml]::new()).LoadXml(@'
<xml>
  <trkpt lat="-33.483478" lon="150.159805">
    <name> p2 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:00:12Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="-33.483852" lon="150.158309">
    <name> p3 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:00:56Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="-33.483943" lon="150.157897">
    <name> p4 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:01:07Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="-33.484066" lon="150.157592">
    <name> p5 </name>
    <time>2021-02-23T00:01:17Z</time>
  </trkpt>
</xml>
'@)

$xml.xml.ChildNodes.ForEach({ 
  $parent = $_
  $null = $parent.ChildNodes.
    Where({ $_.name -eq 'time' }).
    ForEach({ $parent.RemoveChild($_) }) 
})

# Use $xml.Save - with a full output file path - to save the modified XML:
#    $xml.Save("$PWD/processed1.gpx")
```

Note: The above doesn't create *pretty-printed* XML output, i.e. any original pretty-printing is lost.
If pretty-printing is desired, there are two options:

- Set `.PreserveWhitespace` to `$true` on the `[xml]` instance before calling `.Load()` / `.LoadXml()` - however, that may leave a blank line for each element removed.
- Re-perform pretty printing on saving - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582388/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Open a power shell in the directory of your gpx file

use this regex: (?<=beginningstringname)(.*\n?)(?=endstringname)

Run this command

```
             get-content test.gpx | %{$_ -replace "(?<=<time>)(.*?)(?=<\/time>)",""}
```

Then

get-content test.gpx | %{$_ -replace "findText","replaceText"}

Comment: only deletes data in the < time > node, not the tag itself, so its  ```
    <time></time> ``` instead of whole tag deleted

Comment: and I used this, get-content test.gpx | %{$_ -replace "(?<=<time>)(.*?)(?=</time>)",""}

Comment: To summarize: You're performing a different replacement operation (exclusion of the tag names), and you're not solving Benedict's original problem (which stems from a combination of using `Get-Content` without `-Raw` and mistakenly using escape sequence `\`n` in  a _single_-quoted string).