# Copy XML node from one file and append it to another XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-4.0

Please help me out with a PowerShell script for:

1. Deleting a specific `<Section Name="APILibraries">` node in Config-B.xml.
2. Reading a specific `<Section Name="APILibraries">` node from Config-A.xml.
3. Appending in config-B.xml with step 2 out value.

Code Block 1 & 2 are working fine. I'm able to read the value as well as delete the node from config-B.xml. However, in code block 3 the second-last line of the PowerShell script is throwing error like it can't import null node.

Here is the the Config-A.xml which is source and Config-B.xml is the target along with the PowerShell script.

`Config-A.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <Data>
    <Section Name="APILibraries">
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.User" Layer="User" Type="Custom" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.User" FileName="TIMSS.API.User.dll" />
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.User.Generated" Layer="User" Type="Generated" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.User" FileName="Personify.API.User.Generated.dll" />
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.Base" Layer="Base" Type="Custom" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.Base" FileName="TIMSS.API.Base.dll" />
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.Generated" Layer="Base" Type="Generated" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.Generated" FileName="TIMSS.API.Generated.dll" />
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.Core" Layer="Core" Type="Custom" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.Core" FileName="TIMSS.API.Core.dll" />
    </Section>
  </Data>
</Configuration>
```

`Config-B.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <Data>
    <Section Name="APILibraries">
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.Base" Layer="Base" Type="Custom" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.Base" FileName="TIMSS.API.Base.dll" />
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.Generated" Layer="Base" Type="Generated" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.Generated" FileName="TIMSS.API.Generated.dll" />
      <Item Name="TIMSS.API.Core" Layer="Core" Type="Custom" RootNamespace="TIMSS.API.Core" FileName="TIMSS.API.Core.dll" />
    </Section>
  </Data>
</Configuration>
```

PowerShell script:

```bsh
###Code Block - 1 : Get Source XML <Section Name="APILibraries"> Node Value ###
$CustomWinClientConfigXmlSource = "SourcePath\Config.xml"

[xml]$SourceConfigXml = Get-Content -Path "$CustomWinClientConfigXmlSource" -Raw
$SourceXmlNode = $SourceConfigXml | Select-Xml -XPath "//Section[@Name='APILibraries']"
$SourceXmlOutput = Write-Output "$SourceXmlNode"
$SourceXMLNodeValue = "$SourceXmlOutput"


### Code Block - 2 : Get The Target XML <Section Name="APILibraries"> Node Value And Delete It ##
$WinClientConfigFiles = "Config.xml"
$CustomWinClientConfigXmlTarget = "TargetPath\$WinClientConfigFiles"
$Path = "$CustomWinClientConfigXmlTarget"

[Xml]$servicefactoryconfig = Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw
$old = $servicefactoryconfig.SelectSingleNode("/Configuration/Data/Section[@Name='APILibraries']")
$parent = $old.ParentNode
[void] $parent.RemoveChild($old)


### Code Block - 3 : Append The Target XML <Section Name="APILibraries"> With Source XML Node Value ##
try {
    $newNode = [Xml] @"
$SourceXMLNodeValue
"@
} catch {
    Write-Error -Message 'Ignoring The Error Message' -ErrorAction Ignore
}

[void] $parent.AppendChild($servicefactoryconfig.ImportNode($newNode.DocumentElement, $true))

$servicefactoryconfig.Save($path)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell XML importnode from different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944885/powershell-xml-importnode-from-different-file)

Comment: appreciate for your help. If possible to re-modify the existing one  than i would i need to do it. Can you plz help on this - @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Instead of mangling XML objects into strings and then recreating XML objects from those strings just import the node you originally selected from the first XML: `[void] $parent.AppendChild($servicefactoryconfig.ImportNode($SourceXmlNode.Node, $true))`.

Comment: Thanks For the Help. It works for me.However one more help, what if i would like to put same node at certain position in Config-B.xml file.For example I would like to paste it over on second position like : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
   <Data>
   <Section Name="APILibraries">
  </Section>
     <Section Name="APILibraries">
    </Section>
</Data>
</Configuration>

Comment: Thanks for your geat help. It is working for me now. I have re-modified the code with this one :[void] $parent.SelectSingleNode("/Configuration/Data/Section[@Name='Settings']").AppendChild($servicefactoryconfig.ImportNode($SourceXmlNode.Node, $true))